# Php code to scrape the values from other site

Tags: php, dom, xpath, curl, echo

i am trying to get a some values from other site using code below

```
$values = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');

(MISSING CODE)

echo $values;
```

the site has only text all in first row. basically its just a text line. so i need to get 11th to 18th vale from it.

values are not in csv its values are in body tags and view source is `{"token":"ABCDEFGH","expire":2345789542}`   so i need abcdefgh value

Comment: Please provide more details as to what site you want to scrape? "text in first row" doesn't actually mean anything.

Comment: Show us what the text in first row is.

Comment: Not enough information in the question = not enough information in the answers.   similarly I would recommend you to use preg_match.

Comment: i added more info in question and let complete the code by adding preg_match code thanks

Comment: Try something like this, didn't test it though.  preg_match('/token":"([^"]*)"/ims',$values,$matches);var_dump($matches[1]);

Answer (score 1):

If your example is correct, it's a format called JSON. Php has support for it:

```
$decoded = json_decode('{"token":"ABCDEFGH","expire":2345789542}');
echo $decoded->token;
```

outputs

```
ABCDEFGH
```

Comment: It's an object, so `$decoded_response->token`.

Comment: maerlyn can u explain more? please

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use substring on the output value like the one i ve given below

```
substring($values,11,7);
```

Comment: can u please complete the code the line has total 40 values

Comment: need more info for that, atleast post the line in ur question

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the site is returning CSV (a line of comma or tab delimited text?) If so check out [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

An example:

```
$text = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/');
$values = str_getcsv($text);
for ($i=11; $i <= 18; $i++) {print $values[$i]."\n";}
```

Comment: values are not in csv its values are in body tags and view source is {"token":"ABCDEFGH","expire":2345789542} so i need abcdefgh value